# Cannot return `this` from overridden base class method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I cannot return a `this` from a concrete method implementation, even though the signatures are all appropriate. The idea here is to have a fluent builder, so subclassed `BuildNewCar()` needs to return subclass type `SimpleCarBuilder`.

```
public class Car {}

abstract class BaseCarBuilder
{
    public abstract T BuildNewCar<T>();
}

class SimpleCarBuilder : BaseCarBuilder
{
    Car _car;

    public override SimpleCarBuilder BuildNewCar<SimpleCarBuilder>()
    {
        _car = new Car();
        return this;
    }
}
```

I keep getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'SimpleCarBuilder' to 'SimpleCarBuilder'

Comment: What do you want to do ? Do you want to create new instance of Car class ?

Comment: So, what is your question? Note that `SimpleCarBuilder` is bad name for type parameter.

Comment: I did not realize compiler will see `<SimpleCarBuilder>` as type parameter name, I thought I was providing a concrete class type.

Comment: Make your base class generic (not the method) and have the subclass specify the type parameter. `abstract class BaseCarBuilder<T>  { public abstract T BuildNewCar(); }` followed with `class SimpleCarBuilder : BaseCarBuilder<SimpleCarBuilder> { public override SimpleCarBuilder BuildNewCar() {...} }` *probably* with a constraint on the base class `where T: BaseCarBuilder<T>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the BaseCarBuilder to be non-generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is seeing SimpleCarBuilder as the name of your generic type, not as the actual type to use.  It can't convert actual type SimpleCarBuilder to a generic type parameter named SimpleCarBuilder that could actually represent any type.

If you use the implement abstract class feature, you'll see that the compiler uses T as the generic type parameter name.

Comment: In other words, I can provide the concrete `SimpleCarBuilder` type only when I call the method, not when I define its concrete implementation. Duh. Thanks.